# iOS 6 - XCode 4.5.1 - iPad simulator - programatically getting wrong resolution

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios6, simulator

Why is Ipad simulator in XCode 4.5.1 shows wrong size when checking out programatically?

### MainViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

    NSLog(@"self.view width : %f",self.view.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"self.view height : %f", self.view.frame.size.height);

    mTextView  =   [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    [self.view addSubview:mTextView];
}
```

and I am getting output as

```
self.view width : 320.000000
self.view height : 548.000000
```

My project specification

1. Universal project
2. targeting iOS 6.0
3. I am absolutely certain that I checked "**targeted for ipad**"
   checkbox when creating MainViewController
4. Dont know whether it is important, but "with xib for user interface"
   was unchecked.

And here is a screen shot with a textview is added

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try waiting until:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
```

before setting the frame of your UITextView. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527925/determine-frame-bounds-in-viewdidload) you won't have valid geometry for your view before then.

Comment: Yes, it is working correctly in when I set the frame in viewWillAppear. But what surprises me is that I used to do a lot of view setup in viewDidLoad before, and never come across this case.. Is this a new change in ,say iOS 6?

Comment: I don't think so. What are the dimensions of the view in interface builder?

Comment: I didn't use interface builder. As I said in the question, the option **"with xib for user interface"** was unchecked.

Comment: Ok, well I guess if you had a xib that the sizes may come from that at the viewDidLoad stage, and also if you created your viewController using the `- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` then you may see valid looking values at this stage.

Comment: I think, you misunderstood UIViewController and UIView, UIViewController doesn't have an `initWithFrame` method. Anyway I am accepting your answer, as it corrected the problem for me..

Answer (score 0):

Try This code to determine what your computer understand the device:

```
NSRange*  pointRange = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] model] rangeOfString:@"iPad" options:0];

if (pointRange.location == NSNotFound) {

    NSLog(@"iPhone");
}
else

  {
    NSLog(@"iPad");

}
```